# How do I read text files within a custom filetype?

Tags: c++

I am working with a custom file type that behaves similar to a zip file and contains files within it. I'm trying to read a text file in this custom file type, but when I open and parse the text file it returns back information I can't use. Below is how I'm reading it currently:

```
    std::ifstream file("C:\\Ex\\ample\\file.cust\\signature.txt\\");

    // Below is a while loop extracting the items
    // In this example it should extract 9 items
    // Currently it is unable to open properly, it is behaving similar to a zip file
    std::vector <std::string> names;

    while (file)
    {
        std::string s;
        if (!getline(file, s)) break;

        std::istringstream ss(s);
        std::vector<std::string> record;

        while (ss)
        {
            std::string s;
            if (!getline(ss, s, ',')) break;
            names.push_back(s);
        }
    }

    // text output:
    // s = "ƒÃ\x10‰\x1f[ë\vÿpô‹ÏPèÕ\näÿ‹Ç_^]Â\x4"
```

Comment: It sounds like you should be using a library to handle the file format.

Comment: You are trying to read text while the content seems to be binary. You provided too few information.

Comment: @zdf what else can I provide, I'm a bit new so I appreciate the advice!

Comment: Is the file format known, is it yours, can you post it? If it is from a third party and you do not have a format description, you most likely need a library.

Comment: @zdf I can't post it, I'm working on it for someone else. What I understand from the format is that it functions similar to a .zip file. If I were to change the path to "\\file.zip\\signature.txt" the output ends up being the same. So I am trying to in a way read a text file within a zipped folder

Comment: I do not think this works: `std::ifstream file("C:\\Ex\\ample\\file.cust\\signature.txt\\");` with your file called `file.cust` and the `signature.txt` stored *inside* the file. Or was `ifstream` extended to recognize the custom file format?

Comment: `ifstream` does not know about the internal structure of your file. It is your task to navigate inside the file. There are a number of file formats that behave like a file system. You might find the format description and/or a library if you google it. If it really is a custom format, you should ask your client for the library.

Answer (score 0):

If you have come up with this new format, make sure to know how you're writing the file, i.e., what [mode](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) you used to write the file:

```
Constant  |  Explanation
----------|-------------
app       | seek to the end of stream before each write
binary    | open in binary mode
in        | open for reading
out       | open for writing
trunc     | discard the contents of the stream when opening
ate       | seek to the end of stream immediately after open
```

It may help to look at the [ifstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) class definition and the examples [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open).

The file must be read with the same mode with which it was written. As @Someprogrammerdude pointed out in a comment, you seem to be reading binary information, so perhaps something like `.open(filename, std::ios::binary)` could help.

If this doesn't help, you should provide more details on the exact specification of the file format and perhaps some code (if you can share, obviously).